# Proper way to implement "layered" class logic

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, inheritance, overriding

I must admit that I don't know if I have a problem in my design pattern, over-thinking or maybe even just class naming, so any suggestions are welcome. This must be an easy problem but it is rather hard for me to even explain it in words(language barrier), so I will try to do it in code.

For example I'm trying to iterate over a network data stream byte by byte(the task is completely irrelevant to question, just to better explain pseudo-code, please don't say that I use wrong tool to do that). Base class will look something like this:

```
class BaseNetworkIterator implements Iterator {

    protected $stream;
    protected $currentByte;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->stream = open_network_stream();
    }

    /** .... * */
    public function next() {
        $this->currentByte = $this->stream->getByte();
    }

    public function current() {
        return $this->currentByte;
    }

}
```

Now imagine that logic in this class is complicated by itself(not one line per method and there are many more helper methods) but I need to do even more. For example I need to reverse bits order in every byte. I don't want to include this logic in base class as it is already big, so I extend it:

```
class ReverseByte extends BaseNetworkIterator {
    /** .... * */
    public function next() {
        parent::next();
        $this->currentByte = $this->reverseStreamByte($this->currentByte);
    }

    protected function reverseStreamByte($byte) {
        /** .... * */
    }
}
```

And more, I want to completely skip all newlines in this stream(reversed):

```
class SkipNewLine extends ReverseByte {
    /** .... * */
    public function next() {
        do {
            parent::next();
        } while ($this->currentByte === "\n");
    }

}
```

And if we get two consecutive bytes(after all this operations - they may be separated by newlines etc.) equal to "NO", then we must reverse one following byte once more(don't think about it: just something that uses all previous logic and a protected method that was defined in one of the previous classes):

```
class HandleDoubleReverseKeyword extends SkipNewLine {

    const DOUBLE_REVERSE_KEYWORD = 'NO';

    /** .... * */
    public function next() {
        parent::next();
        if ($this->getTwoCharsCache() === self::DOUBLE_REVERSE_KEYWORD) {
            $this->currentByte = $this->reverseStreamByte($this->currentByte);
            $this->clearTwoCharsCache();
        } else {
            $this->saveMaxTwoCharsCache($this->currentByte);
        }
    }

    private function saveMaxTwoCharsCache($newChar) {
        /** .... * */
    }

    private function getTwoCharsCache() {
        /** .... * */
    }

    private function clearTwoCharsCache() {
        /** .... * */
    }

}
```

And now although logic is split between classes rather nicely for my taste(each consecutive class does something completely different and isolated and it is easy to see what is done in each layer) it is a mess to work with. If we add new "filter" in the middle we must change what later class is extended from... Naming starts to get insane as "HandleDoubleReverseKeyword" doesn't explain what this class really does even remotely (even if we are in "NetworkIterator" namespace). I don't really understand what a "final" class should look like.

I was thinking of using traits as naming goes much easier there but they cause more problems then solve(execution order, code completion etc.).

I was also thinking of using Yii-like "behaviour/event" pattern (Something like: base next() method consecutively calls an array of class/methods and some external source can add more class/methods to that array instead of extending base class) but there is a huge problem with properties/methods visibility(it is a problem, basically I have to make ALL properties and methods public) and more importantly it is not clear how to properly access methods of other additional classes.

Ok, this still may be not very clear so any feedback is appreciated. I know there is no question mark in this "question", but I hope my intentions are clear and the only thing that comes to mind is: how to do this type of design properly?

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

1. The stream should be separated from the iterator class and its sub classes. Iterator defines how to access the data, each iterator instance should only hold the reference to the data, not the actual data.
2. The logic in class HandleDoubleReverseKeyword is about how to process the data, not how to access the data; and the action is decided base on what the data is, so the class should not inherited from the iterator class; here I think we can use the state pattern.

So the code to deal with the stream could be like this:

```
$stream = open_network_stream();
$iterator it = new Iterator(&stream);
$data = it->next(); 
while(data){
  switch(data->value){
     case 'A': AcitionA->action();break;
     case 'B': AcitionB->action();break;
     }
$data = it->next();
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time! The problem with this approach is that in the end I want to have a "clean" iterator for further processing. I mean that in my design last layer "FinalNetworkIterator" will be used in another code for much more complicated analysis(tokens, parsing, logic etc.), the job of this iterator is solely to "clean" the stream from the most primitive obstacles. If I implement logic like this then all of it will be in one place and it will be really hard to separate it. I don't want basic byte by byte analysis to be in the same place as parsing tokens logic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are approaching this from the wrong perspective.

The current hierarchy you have in place highly limits the re-usability of each component, since they are all implemented to work only on the result of a byte stream iterator. If for example you needed to implement a file iterator, and then skip over each new line, you cannot possibly reuse your existing `SkipNewLine`, because it works only on the result of a reverse byte iterator.

Another fallacy is that you have no way to control the order in which each of this steps occurred without rewriting the entire class structure. Even something as simply as moving the `SkipNewLine` class before the `ReverseByte` (or after the `HandleDoubleReverseKeyword`) is a refactoring nightmare.

I suggest you implement each step in the iteration as a separate class, that solely acts on a generic stream, and makes no assumptions as to the state of the source stream. You can inject an instance of each of these components into your `BaseNetworkIterator`, and use them independently of each other.

This will further provide you with the ability to act on each of the individual states with knowledge of the global state of the iteration.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time! I understand that this design is really bad and I completely agree with your points and I know about them, it is just the list of what is wrong with this design is too long and I didn't think it is useful to write it all. About your suggestion: "that solely acts on a generic stream" - I don't know how to properly do that. For example in my bad design HandleDoubleReverseKeyword will work properly on a stream like "N\n\n\nO" because removing newlines was done on a previous layer, how can I make it independent?

Comment: Then there is a problem that I want to be able to reuse methods added on previous layer(like "reverseStreamByte"), maybe I approach this from the wrong side?

Comment: That idea is that you process the stream one step at a time (you could do it one byte at the time depending on the type of operations you do). If there is a dependency between steps (like `HandleDoubleReverseKeyword` requiring no new lines) that's a problem that should be handle by a coordinator class that knows about all the steps, not by each specific class.

Comment: Imagine you are handling one byte at a time: what steps does this byte need to go through? Isolate each step into it is own class to make them reusable, and make sure they do not make assumptions regarding previous or next steps.

Comment: I tried to do this at first, but what I'm writing is much more complicated. The biggest problem is that I need to reuse a lot of code written in "processing" classes in other "processing" classes. If "reverseStreamByte" problem can be solved in other ways(still ugly ways), then what to do when I need to reuse the "TwoCharsCache" in another "processing" class to make and action on encountering "OK" message? Create completely new cache? I must reuse a lot of things that I add on different "layers", they depend on each other in more ways then order. Is it inherently wrong?

Comment: It is 2AM here, I have to go to sleep now. Just to give you more ideas about real code I do: not all "processing" iterators are stateless. For example there is a layer that will cache N bytes and the number of bytes it caches depends on the biggest needs of further layers(One layers tells it to cache 4 bytes, another tells it to cache 10, so it will cache 10 and use the same cache for both of this cases). Then there is and "expand" layer that will turn for example "tl;dr" into "too long;didn't read" on the fly and further layers will iterate over the long message as it was original stream,etc.